What does it mean to "suppose" a proposition in proofs?
I have been putting some thought lately to proofs by contradiction and have the following question.
When proving theorems we usually use the word "Suppose P(x)" where P is a proposition, but what do we mean by "suppose"? All propositions are either T or F, and, under some interpretation, their truth value is fixed.
Hence, under some interpretation, if proposition P is F, in proofs by contradiction if we say "suppose P is T". But how can this make sense, if the proposition's truth value is FIXED.
Does the point I am making make sense? I can understand how we can use proofs by contradictions and understand WHY they work once we have formalized the notions of a logical language, but before doing or knowing that, it seems crazy to me how proofs by contradiction are seen as something that is so natural and intuitive. I can see why we could THINK that proofs by contradiction are valid and hence expect them to be valid once we have formalized the language but I cannot see how we can be CERTAIN that proofs by contradiction are valid relying only on our intuition. Am I crazy? (I hope not)

Edited so that the question is opened once again. I leave some things I have previously wrote since the answer refers back to them:
I interpret the word "suppose" as being adequate only for the first category of propositions. It makes sense to "suppose" that a proposition is either T or F if that proposition can be T in some scenarios but F in others.
However, it does not make any sense to me to say "suppose p(x)" if p is a proposition of the second category. This is the backbone of any proof by contradiction. For example, when we want to prove that "$\sqrt 2$ is not rational" we begin by supposing "$\sqrt 2$ is rational" and then proceed to derive a contradiction. But the proposition "$\sqrt 2$ is irrational" is of the second category, since it is the case that the propositions is either T or F in ALL scenarios. So how can we "fix" any truth value to that proposition since its truth value is already fixed?

Consider the  statement "$X^n+Y^n=Z^n$ has no non-trivial integer solutions". This can be true or false, depending on $n$. But for each $n$, it can only be true or false. So your two categories are the same. They just differ by the exact wording of the statement.

Your initial example is just vaguely worded. If the claim were "given any two sets $A,B$, we have $|A\cup B|=4$" it is unambiguously false.  If it were "there exist two sets $A,B$ such that $|A\cup B|=4$" then it is unambiguously true.

It is not true that "$1+1=3$" is false under all scenarios. It depends entirely on the interpretation of the symbols 1, +, =, and 3. It is false under the usual interpretation of those symbols, but you are actually supposing that the symbols carry certain meanings in order to claim that the statement is false.

Can't you suppose anything you want?  “What if I were a billionaire?”  “What if I were king of the world?” “What if leprechauns were real?”  “What if Germany had won World War II?”   These are propositions which, as you put it, are true or false—and they are false.  But you can still explore the consequences of what else might be true if they were true.

Contrary to your title, this isn't about proofs by contradiction. It seems rather to be about the Deduction Theorem.

"True" and "false" are semantic notions. They depend on the meaning of a proposition. The meaning of a proposition has to do with how we interpret the symbols in that propostion. This is matter of the model we are using.
By contrast, "provable" and "unprovable" are syntactic notions. They depend on the syntax (on the rules we have for manipulating our symbols), and not the meaning. They depend on the formal theory.
So we are already in a bit  of a quandary when you try to argue that propositions are either "always true", "always false", or "sometimes true and sometimes false". You seem to be thinking exclusively in terms of models/interpretations. Note that your statement that "$1+1=3$ under all scenarios is F" is not correct: that depends on the meaning of the symbols 1, +, =, and 3. You are really saying "If the symbols 1, +, =, and 3 have their usual interpretation, then the formula $1+1=3$ is false." But if they have different meanings, then the statement can be true. We can define a group structure on the set $\{1,3\}$ with operation $+$ in which $3+3=3$, $3+1=1$, $1+3=1$, and $1+1=3$. In this group, "$1+1=3$" is true.

When proving some theorems, we usually use the words "Suppose P(x)" where P(x) is a proposition. But what do we mean by 'suppose'?

Many (most?) theorems are really statements of the form "If A then B". When we are trying to prove such a theorem, we usually use the Deduction Theorem. The Deduction Theorem is a metatheorem (a theorem about theorems) that says that if you have a formal system $\Delta$, then any proof of $B$ obtained in the system $\Delta\cup\{A\}$ (that is, a system in which we add the statement $A$ as an axiom) can be transformed, in a specific algorithmic way, into a formal proof of $A\to B$ in the system $\Delta$. That justifies the usual method or argument in which, when we are trying to prove that in our system $A$ implies $B$, we are allowed to add $A$ to our axioms (colloquially, to suppose that $A$ is true), and use that additional axiom/assumption to deduce $B$. If we are able to do that, then we have in fact proven that under our usual system, $A\to B$ is a theorem.
That is the meaning of "suppose P(x)". We are engaging in a use of the Deduction Theorem in order to prove that an implication can be deduced.
You seem to be arguing that it only makes sense to use the Deduction Theorem when the formula P(x) is not a tautology (not a formula that is true in every interpretation of the symbols) or a contradiction (a formula that is false in every interpretation of the symbols). But this is not the case. The Deduction Theorem is applicable for any kind of formula $A$, not merely those that are not tautologies
Note that the Deduction Theorem can also be used to justify proofs by contrapositive: since under the usual rules of logic, the proposition $A\to B$ is logically equivalent to the proposition $(\neg B)\to(\neg A)$, that means that we can  use the Deduction to Theorem to prove $A\to B$ by first proving that $\neg A$ is a consequence  of $\Delta\cup\{\neg B\}$; this shows that $\neg B\to\neg A$ is a consequence of $\Delta$. And since the tautology $(\neg B\to \neg A)\to (A\to B)$ is provable from $\Delta$, we deduce that $A\to B$ is provable from $\Delta$.
Proof by Contradiction also relies on the Deduction Theorem, together with some additional assumptions.
Everyone (including intuitionists, by the way) agrees that if the addition of $P$ to our axioms $\Delta$ results in a statement of the form $A\wedge\neg A$, then we are allowed to deducee that our axioms $\Delta$ imply $\neg P$. This follows from two basic logical assumptions incorporated into most of our systems. One is the propositional tautology that $(P\to\neg P)\to\neg P$. The other is the principle of non-contradiction or consistency, which says that the statement $(A\wedge \neg A)\to B$ is true: from a contradictory statement we can deduce anything. So if from $\Delta\cup \{P\}$ we can deduce $A\wedge\neg A$, then from $\Delta\cup\{P\}$ we can deduce $\neg P$. Then using the deduction Theorem we have that $\Delta$ allows us to prove $(P\to\neg P)$. Together with the tautology $(P\to\neg P)\to\neg P)$, Modus Ponens tells us that from $\Delta$ we can deduce $\neg P$. This is the essence of Proof by Contradiction: showing that $\Delta$ implies $\neg P$ is equivalent to showing that $\Delta\cup\{P\}$ implies a statement of the form $A\wedge\neg A$.
If we now add the law of excluded middle (which can be phrased as $(\neg(\neg P))\to P$), then we also obtain that to prove that from $\Delta$ we can deduce $P$, we may instead show that from $\Delta\cup\{\neg P\}$ we may deduce a contradiction $A\wedge\neg A$. From the argument above we obtain that this is equivent to showing that from $\Delta$ we can deduce $\neg(\neg P)$. Now use $(\neg(\neg P))\to P$ and $\neg(\neg P)$, together with Modus Ponens, to conclude that from $\Delta$ you can deduce $P$. (It is this last step that intuitionists reject, not 'proof by contradiction' writ large).

Very neat answer!

Great answer, thank you so so much! Quick follow-up question: nowadays we can confidently claim everything you have written in your answer to my question. However, in the times of Ancient Greece, how would Euclid for example be confident when proving his theorems without the notion of a formal language? I am in my first year of maths at university and upon asking my professor about these types of ideas ( formal logical systems) he told me that it was not important for me to focus on that, do you agree with this? If so, how can then I be sure that I am reasoning validly / correctly?

What I am trying to get at is that why do we usually consider all of this to be intuitive? I deal with this in my last part of my question.  I see that it is intuitive to some extent but I think that my question cannot be rigourously answered without having established these formalities prior, no?

@AgustinG. It is true that the formal notions are much newer; they arose from the crisis of foundations in Mathematics that followed the discovery of non-Euclidean geoemtries, the foundations of calculus, and the foundations of set theory. Before then, people were (and to a large extend continue to) work with mostly intuitive notions of what is a valid argument in a proof and what is not. This works most of the time (it can be properly formalized), but leads to issues from time to time. Euclid was perhaps too confident, given that his very first proposition is not properly justified!

@AgustinG. So we don't normally worry about the formal details, confident that if an issue arises we now know how to deal with the issue. Just like we don't really worry about what a real number "really" is, knowing it can be justified in any number of ways. Same with arguments. We have certain types of argument that we have verified formally are valid, and use them. Many were used traditionally. Some that were used traditionally are questioned by some (see constructivists/intuitionists). Some more complex arguments, though, can give rise to debate and doubts of validity.(cont)

@AgustinG. For example, the claimed proof of the ABC Conjecture by Schinizi Mochizuki has led to a disagreement between Mochizuki on one side and Scholze and Stix on the other of whether the argument contains a logical error or not.

@ArturoMagidin I have just one last question. When doing a proof by contradiction we show that if not(P) is T, then P is T (1). And thus conclude that not(P) is F (2). However, this jump from our premise (1) to our conclusion (2) is not the "smallest logical jump" we can take, right? In our minds, this is so obvious that we do usually do not show any more reasoning between (1) and (2). However, what is going on behind the scenes is that we show that not(p) implies p, this means that not(p) implies p AND not(p), the latter is a contradiction and so T implies not(not(p)) and (cont).

@ArturoMagidin by double negation not(not(p)) is p. So p is true, and like this we ARE taking the "smallest logical steps" ( I am not sure how to say this phrase formally, I am picturing the steps that a machine or computer would, almost mechanically, take to arrive from (1) to (2)). Is this correct?

@AgustinG. Sorry, I don't like chat. When doing a proof by contradiction we do not always prove that not(P) implies P. Sometimes we prove that not(P) implies some absurd thing. That absurd thing could be "Not(P) and P", but it might be something else entirely. Again: we have metatheorems that say "if you can do X, this implies that you can also do Y". When we try to do Y, we may do so by doing X alone, and letting that metatheorem do the rest. There is no requirement for proofs to employ only the "smallest logical step" available, only thatvthecsteps be valid.

@ArturoMagidin Ok. But at some point, in order to show that the steps are valid, we would have needed to take the "smallest step" path, no? I am not sure I understand you when you say: "When we try to do Y, we may do so by doing X alone, and letting that metatheorem do the rest." And by the way thank you so much for your replies.

@AgustinG. No. We are never required to take thec"smallest step". We are only required to ensure all our steps are valid. As to the other: Suppose you need to drive to Albuquerque. You are not sure you know how to get from where you are to Albuquerque. But you do know how to get from Saganaw to Albuquerque: you already did it once, or you have driving directions, whatever. That means that in order to ensure that you can drive to Albuquerque, I may simply tell you how to get to Saganaw. I don't need to worry about the rest. Metatheorems guarantee you can get from Saganaw to Albuquerque.

@ArturoMagidin Ok, perfect. Great analogy. I understand. I think that I did not articulate myself correctly in my previous comment, though. Continuing with your analogy, what I was trying to get at is the following. If I already know how to get from Saganaw to Albuquerque then it is enough for you to tell me how to get to Saganaw and metatheorems take care of the rest. BUT if you tell me how to get to Saganaw and I previously have never travelled from Saganaw to Albuquerque then metatheorems here are not enough. And it is here where I would need to apply the "smallest steps" to know how (cont)

@ArturoMagidin to get from Saganaw to Albuquerque. And once I do it I never have to do it again. If you were to hand me a guide with several steps detailing how I can get from Saganaw to Albuquerque (without me previously having gone for S to A), then in order to convince me those steps need to be either steps I can previously understand (other metatheorems) or a "smallest step", or otherwise I might question you.

@AgustinG. I do not understand your fixation with "smallest steps". If you've never gone from Saganaw to Albuquerque, you just need a way to get from Saganaw to Albuquerque. You don't need "the best possible way" or "the fastest way", or "the shortest way". Just a way. If you are not aware of why you can prove that $A\to B$ by assuming $A$, then you ask, sure. But once that is explained, you are done. This can be done formally (Deduction Theorem), or informally ("either $A$ is true or false; if it is false, the implication is true and you are done; so we just check the case when $A$").

Ok, perfect. Understood. Thank you, Arturo. :)

You claim when proving the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ we cannot say “suppose $\sqrt{2}$ is rational” because the statement falls into the second category. That is, we know for a fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is indeed irrational. But when we are proving “$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational” it is not a fact.
